# Flux of vector field in a plane

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus, partial-differential-equations, definite-integrals

> Compute the flow of the vector field $F(x, y, z) = (0, 0, z)$ up through
> the part of the plane $x + y + z = 1$ that lies in the first octant.

***My take on it:***

We have that $z= 1-x-y$ and $0≤y≤1-x$ and $0\le x$ but I am not sure about the upper bounds for $x$ (Can someone explain that?).

Anyways I get $(x,y,1-x-y)$ and then I partial differentiated this and got $f_x=(1,0,-1)$ and $f_y = (0,1,-1)$. Then I took the cross product of the two vectors and it is (1,1,1). So my integrand is the dot product of $(0,0,z)$ and $(1,1,1)$. This obviously equals to $z$. And the absolute value of the cross product vector is $\sqrt{3}$. I then just randomly said $x\le 1$ and got:

$$\sqrt{3}\iint_D 1-x-y \,dx\,dy = \frac{\sqrt{3}}{3}$$

Answer (score 1):

Please read [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4685250/949989) why in this situation you should not normalize the vector $(1,1,1)\,.$ So there is no $\sqrt{3}\,.$ The bounds to every coordinate are $[0,1]$ which should answer one of your questions. The integral itself should be
\begin{align}
&\int_0^1\int_0^{1-x}(1-x-y)\,dy\,dx=\int_0^1\Big(1-x-x(1-x)-\frac{(1-x)^2}{2}\Big)\,dx\\[3mm]
&=\int_0^1\frac{(1-x)^2}{2}\,dx=\frac{1}{6}\,.
\end{align}

Comment: But I didn't normalize the vector tho, I just calculated the magnitude of the vector which was $\sqrt{3}$.

Comment: Whatever your intention was with that gratuitous calculation of $\sqrt{3}\,.$ Your [similar question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4693962/flux-through-a-plane) shows by using the divergence theorem that $1/6$ is the correct solution.