# Flux through a plane

Tags: multivariable-calculus, divergence-theorem

Calculate the flux of the vector field $F(x, y, z) = (0, 0, z)$ up through the part of the plane $x + y + z = 1$ that lies in the f rst octant, by closing to the surface and using the divergence theorem.

Usually I'd have something to say but this time I don't even know where to begin. I have a plane right so what do I do now?

Comment: Maybe think of a pyramid with its vertex at the origin and the surface you're given as its base?

Comment: Hint: Use a variant of the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus. Strong hint: https://openstax.org/books/calculus-volume-3/pages/6-8-the-divergence-theorem

Comment: @SeanRoberson OP already knows to use the divergence theorem.

Answer (score 2):

Notice that the plane intersects the first quadrant at the points $(1,0,0)$, $(0,1,0)$, and $(0,0,1)$. We create a closed volume with the desired surface on its boundary by considering the tetrahedron created by these vertices and the vertex at the origin, $(0,0,0)$. In set notation, this volume is given by $\Omega = \{(x,y,z)\in\mathbb{R}^3:x,y,z\geq 0\text{ and }x+y+z \leq 1\}$. The boundary of this region consists of four faces, one lying on each of the planes $x,y,z=0$ and the fourth being the the surface we are interested in. We label these surfaces $S_1$, $S_2$, $S_3$, and $S_4$, respectively.

The divergence theorm tells us that
$$
\int_\Omega\nabla\cdot F dV = \int_{\partial\Omega} F\cdot \hat{n}dS.
$$
We will compute each of these integrals, compare, then use them to evaluate the flux through $S_4$, which is what we want.

First notice that $\nabla\cdot F = 1$, so we have
$$
\int_\Omega\nabla\cdot F dV = \int_\Omega dV = \int_0^1\int_0^{1-x}\int_0^{1-x-y}  dzdydx =\frac{1}{6}.
$$

We now compute the surface integral. We can decompose the boundary of $\Omega$ into integrals over the four surfaces defined earlier:
$$
\int_{\partial\Omega} F\cdot \hat{n}dS = \int_{S_1} F\cdot \hat{n}dS+\int_{S_2} F\cdot \hat{n}dS+\int_{S_3} F\cdot \hat{n}dS+\int_{S_4} F\cdot \hat{n}dS.
$$
Now, notice that $F\perp \hat{n}$ on both $S_1$ and $S_2$, so their dotproduct in the integrand is $0$. Additionally, $F=0$ on $S_3$ since $z=0$, so this integral is $0$ as well. We then have
$$
\int_{\partial\Omega} F\cdot \hat{n}dS = \int_{S_4} F\cdot \hat{n}dS.
$$

Combining this with the Divergence Theorem, we have

$$
\frac{1}{6} = \int_\Omega\nabla\cdot F dV = \int_{\partial\Omega} F\cdot \hat{n}dS = \int_{S_4} F\cdot \hat{n}dS, 
$$
so the flux through $S_4$ is equal to $1/6$.

Comment: thanks for the help but what suggests that I'm dealing with a tetrahedron? When I intially was sketching the graph I got something that looks like a triangle. I'm asking because (0,0,0) is not on the plane.

Comment: This was the same idea I suggested in my hint above. You need to create a *closed* surface with this triangle as one part of it. This is the most natural surface that comes to my mind. If I gave you a closed disk (circle and its interior), you might naturally think of a hemisphere or a paraboloid.

Comment: @Need_MathHelp The most natural way to apply the divergence theorem in this context is to construct a closed volume with this triangular section of the plane as part of its boundary. This particular tetrahedron is one such shape and it probably results in the easiest computation