# Using surface integral to calculate the flux of vector field through two surfaces

Tags: multivariable-calculus, surface-integrals, divergence-theorem

I really would appreciate it if someone could help me with this problem below that I am having trouble with. The problem that I am trying to ask is down below, hyperlinked. Thank you.

Here is what I have done so far with the problem.

$S_1$ can be parametrized into $r(\theta,z) = <sin\theta, cos\theta, z>$. The Jacobian transform gives $r_{\theta} \times r_{z} = \, <cos\theta ,sin\theta ,0>$

$S_2$ can be parametrized into $r(\phi,\theta)=<sin\phi\, cos\theta, sin\phi\,sin\theta, cos\phi+1>$.
The Jacobian transform gives  $r_{\phi} \times r_{\theta} = \, <sin^2\phi cos\theta ,-(sin\phi)^2sin\theta ,2sin\phi cos\theta>$.

$$S_1:\int_0^{2\pi}\int_0^1F(r(\theta,z))\cdot<cos\theta,sin\theta,0>\,dzd\theta$$
$$S_2:\int_0^{2\pi}\int_0^{\pi/2}F(r(\phi,\theta))\cdot<sin^2\phi cos\theta ,-(sin\phi)^2sin\theta ,2sin\phi cos\theta>\,d\phi d\theta$$
After calculating the two double integrals for $S_1$ and $S_2$, adding the two values should give the answer, is that right?
I really would appreciate if someone could help answer my question, even if just briefly. Thank you.

[Click here to see Problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GPNd6.png)

Comment: The normal vector in the integral for $S_2$ looks dubious. There is a simpler way of getting it: $S_2$ is the upper hemisphere around $(0,0,1)$ who's normal vectors in Cartesian coordinates are $2(x,y,z-1)\,.$ Now use polar coordinates. [This](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4685167/stokes-theorem-normalization/4685250#4685250) might be simpler to practice those things. Your $F$ looks more complicated than necessary for teaching the essentials on surface integrals.

Comment: Thank you very much sir. Yes I have also felt the calculations were a bit unnecessarily complicated. If I take the normal vector $2(x,y,z-1)$ and use polar coordinates, am I ending up with a double integral of $2F(\theta,z)\cdot(cos\theta,sin\theta,z-1)$?

Comment: I was wondering about this factor $2$ myself. Maybe it should not be there. As explained in the link the correct normal is your cross product $r_\phi\times r_\theta\,.$ However you can use the polar coordinate version of $(x,y,z-1)$ to sanity check if you calculated that cross product correctly.

Comment: Yep. Thank you sir.

Comment: You can also close the surface by glueing $x^2+y^2\leq 1,z=0$ and then using divergence theorem. Have you considered this approach?