# Calculating flux, question about orientation and sign of integral

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration, analytic-geometry

Let $$B=\{(x,y,z) \in R^3 : x^2+y^2=4z\}$$

$$L=\{(x,y,z) \in R^3 : x=2, y=0\}$$

Let $P$ be a fragment of $B$ of points such that distance from them to $L$ is less than 1. $P$ is oriented as follows: in any point, normal vector giving positive side has positive $z$ component.

Calculate flux over vector field $F(x,y,z)=(\frac{-y}{z},\frac{x}{z}, \frac{y}{x-z})$ through $P$ from negative to positive side.

So I calculated that $P=\{(x,y,z) \in R^3 : x^2+y^2=4z, (x-2)^2+y^2<1\}$ and that normal vector giving positive side points inwards. I considered parametrization $f(u,v)=(u,v,\frac{u^2+v^2}{4})$ from $\operatorname{Ball} K=\{(u-2)^2+v^2<1\}$ to $P$.

So:

$$\operatorname{Flux} = \int_P\frac{-y}{z}dy \wedge dz -\frac{x}{z} dx \wedge dz + \frac{y}{x-z} dx \wedge dy=(\color{red}{\pm1})\int_K \frac{-v}{\frac{u^2+v^2}{4}}(\frac{-u}{2})-\frac{u}{v}(\frac{v}{2})+\frac{v}{u-\frac{u^2+v^2}{4}}\qquad (1)$$

and I am not sure about the sign after equality (in red). I think it should be negative because normal point inwards, can you explain it and check if everything before is correct?

Answer (score 1):

My previous answer was too involved and came to the wrong conclusion for some reason.

The answer is you need the plus sign.

The surface $B$ is the boundary of an elliptic paraboloid. I gather that $z\ge 0\,.$ The inward pointing unit normal vector at $B$ is
$$\tag{1}
\mathbf{n}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2+4}}\begin{pmatrix}-x\\-y\\2\end{pmatrix}\,.
$$
Following Ted Shifrin's comment: The normal vector is
$$\tag{2}
\frac{\partial f}{\partial u}\times \frac{\partial f}{\partial v}=\begin{pmatrix}1\\0\\\frac{u}{2}\end{pmatrix}\times \begin{pmatrix}0\\1\\\frac{v}{2}\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}-\frac{u}{2}\\-\frac{v}{2}\\\color{red}{+}1\end{pmatrix}
$$
when surface  parametrized by $f(u,v)=(u,v,(u^2+v^2)/4)^\top\,.$
The normal vector (2) has positive $z$-component and points inward like $\mathbf{n}$ does.

The flux of $F$ through $P$ in the direction of those normal vectors is
$$
\int_PF\cdot \mathbf{n}\,dS=
\int_K
 F\cdot\Big\{\frac{\partial f}{\partial u}\times \frac{\partial f}{\partial v}\Big\}\,du\,dv\,.\tag{3}
$$
(The reason why the cross product does not need to be normalized
is discussed in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4685250/949989).)

To bring (3) into a notation using differential forms we write
$f=(x,y,z)^\top\,.$ Then the components of $\{\frac{\partial f}{\partial u}\times \frac{\partial f}{\partial v}\}\,du\,dv
$ are
\begin{align}
\Big\{\frac{\partial y}{\partial u}\frac{\partial z}{\partial v}-\frac{\partial z}{\partial u}\frac{\partial y}{\partial v}\Big\}\,du\,dv
&=dy\wedge dz\,,\\
\Big\{\frac{\partial z}{\partial u}\frac{\partial x}{\partial v}-\frac{\partial x}{\partial u}\frac{\partial z}{\partial v}\Big\}\,du\,dv
&=dz\wedge dx\,,\\
\Big\{\frac{\partial x}{\partial u}\frac{\partial y}{\partial v}-\frac{\partial y}{\partial u}\frac{\partial x}{\partial v}\Big\}\,du\,dv
&=dx\wedge dy\,.
\end{align}
Therefore with the desired inward orientation of $\mathbf{n}$ the flux is
$$
\int_PF\cdot \mathbf{n}\,dS=\int_PF_x\,dy\wedge dz+F_y\,dz\wedge dx+F_z\,dx\wedge dy\,.
$$
In your case this is calculated by the RHS of (3) and using (2) as
$$
\int_K\frac{-v}{\frac{u^2+v^2}{4}}(\frac{-u}{2})-\frac{u}{\color{red}{\frac{u^2+v^2}{4}}}(\frac{v}{2})+\frac{v}{u-\frac{u^2+v^2}{4}}\,du\,dv
$$
where I fixed an error of yours.

Comment: +1 Congrats on hitting 10k reputation by the way.

Comment: @IraeVid That was hard work :)

Comment: I don't understand why it works

Comment: @romperextremeabuser I just corrected an error but the result (minus sign) is the same. The idea is that flux is the integral of $F\cdot\mathbf{n}$ and that surface area the same integral when $F=\mathbf{n}\,.$ In the back of my mind I have the old fashioned way of writing a surface integral $\int_P F\cdot\mathbf{n}\,dS\,.$ When $F=\mathbf{n}$ this is (2).

Comment: Why does the flux have to be positive? You need to check that the parametrization is compatible with the orientation stated in the question. Maybe you did this and I just missed it.

Comment: @TedShifrin . Thanks for joining the discussion. They want $\mathbf{n}$ to be inward pointing and calculate the flux of $F$ against that $\mathbf{n}\,.$ Then a question of a sign in front of an integral arises. Therefore I thought that the flux of $\mathbf{n}$ itself should be positive given that orientation of $\mathbf{n}\,.$ The flux of $F$ can have any sign just not the flux of $\mathbf{n}\,.$ The latter needs to be positive.

Comment: Oh, I see what you did. It's too involved. I would just check that $\frac{\partial f}{\partial u}\times\frac{\partial f}{\partial v}$ has a positive $z$-component (as is specified for $\mathbf n$). It does. So we pull back and want $h(u,v)\,du\wedge dv$, not $dv\wedge du$.

Comment: @TedShifrin . Yes too involved. Esp. as  I had to fix yet another mistake in (2) making it even more involved.

Comment: @romperextremeabuser . A better answer is given now. I just realised that in the previous  answer I took the wrong $K$ to integrate.

Comment: So I should pick + sign right? If I wanted to calculate flux from positive to negative side I woyld pick - sign?

Comment: Right. $\phantom{.}$