# surface integral with vector field, using cylindrical coordinates

Tags: differential-geometry, cylindrical-coordinates

I want to compute a surface-integral, but using cylindrical coordinates.

I'll denote the Cartesian coordinate system on $\mathbb{R^3}$ by $\mathbb{R}^3_{xyz}$, and the cylindrical by $\mathbb{R}^3_{\rho \theta z}$. Let $$\textbf{F}(x,y,z) = \begin{bmatrix}F_x(x,y,z) \\ F_y(x,y,z) \\ F_z(x,y,z) \end{bmatrix}$$
be a vector-field. Let $S \subset \mathbb{R}^3_{xyz}$ be the surface I've marked in black on the right below. I wish to compute the flux of $\textbf{F}$ out of $S$, i.e. $\int_S \textbf{F} \cdot \hat{n} \, dS $, where $\hat{n}$ is a unit-vector normal to $S$, pointing outward. Clearly, this calls for cylindrical coordinates. Denote by

$$ \phi(\rho, \theta, z) =\begin{bmatrix} \rho \cos \theta \\  \rho \sin \theta \\ z\end{bmatrix} \quad , \quad \phi^{-1}(x,y,z) =\begin{bmatrix} \sqrt{x^2+y^2} \\ \arctan(y,x)  \\ z\end{bmatrix} $$
the standard change-of-variables. In orange I've drawn $\phi^{-1}(S)$.

My approach (which I'm not sure of):
I can write $\textbf{F}$ as a two-form: $\alpha = F_x \, dy \wedge dz \ +  \  F_y \, dz \wedge dx \ +\  F_z \, dx \wedge dy$. And then try to pull it back, i.e. compute $\phi^{\star} \alpha$. However I don't know how to compute $\phi^{\star}(dy \wedge dz)$ (or any other one, for that matter). Even then - How do I treat the $\hat{n}$ part?
Somehow I feel there must be some nice way to compute the surface-integral. This is all in part for eventually computing the divergence of $\textbf{F}$ using cylindrical coordinates.
[image: Cylindrical plot]

---

**First Edit**:

Following the suggestion, I'm instead using a simpler parametrization for $S$. Let $f(\rho, z)=(\rho \cos \theta, \rho \sin \theta, z)$. Then we can compute and get that the normal pointing out of the black surface $S$ is:

$$\tag{1} \hat{n} = \textbf{-} \big(\frac{\partial f}{\partial \rho} \times \frac{\partial f}{\partial z}\big) = - \begin{bmatrix} \sin \theta \\ \cos \theta \\ 0 \end{bmatrix}$$

if we write down

$$\tag{2} \textbf{F} = F_\rho \hat{\rho} + F_\theta \hat{\theta} + F_z \hat{z} = \begin{bmatrix} F_\rho \cos \theta - F_{\theta} \sin \theta \\ F_\rho \sin \theta + F_\theta \cos \theta \\ F_z  \end{bmatrix} $$
then

$$\tag{3}  \textbf{F} \cdot \hat{n} =  \begin{bmatrix} F_\rho \cos \theta - F_{\theta} \sin \theta \\ F_\rho \sin \theta + F_\theta \cos \theta \\ F_z  \end{bmatrix} \cdot \begin{bmatrix} -\sin \theta \\ -\cos \theta \\ 0 \end{bmatrix} = -2 F_{\rho} \sin \theta \cos \theta + F_\theta (\sin ^2 \theta - \cos^2 \theta)$$

And I don't see how that helps me. I wish to compute sums of surfaces integrals, and then finally diving by the volume, in order to compute the divergence.

---

**Second edit**:

Somewhere in my computation of the div formula I have a mistake, since I don't get the right result:

I'm given $\textbf{F} = F_{\rho} \hat{\rho} + F_{\theta} \hat{\theta} + F_z \hat{z}$. Let $V \subset \mathbb{R}^3_{\rho \theta z}$ be the box depiected on the left, with sides length $\Delta \rho, \Delta \theta, \Delta z$. Let $\Delta V$ denote the volume of V, then $\Delta V = \Delta \rho \cdot \Delta \theta \cdot \Delta z$. Let $(\rho_0, \theta_0, z_0)$ be a point right in the center of the box. I wish to compute

$$\tag{4} \mathop{div} \textbf{F} = \lim_{\Delta V \to 0} \frac{1}{\Delta V} \int_{\partial V} \textbf{F} \cdot \hat{n} \mathop{dS}$$
Let $S_1, \ldots, S_6$ denote the six faces of the box. Then
$$ \int_{\partial V} \textbf{F} \cdot \hat{n} \mathop{dS} = \int_{S_1} \textbf{F} \cdot \hat{n}_{S_1} \mathop{dS} + \ldots + \int_{S_6} \textbf{F} \cdot \hat{n}_{S_6} \mathop{dS} $$

Let $S_1$ be the face drawn in orange. Then $\hat{n}_{S_1} = \begin{bmatrix} 0 \\ -1 \\ 0 \end{bmatrix}_{(\hat{\rho}, \hat{\theta},\hat{z})}$. We can approximate the flux out of $S_1$ by evaluating $\textbf{F} \cdot \hat{n}_{S_1}$ at some point on $S_1$, and multiplying by the area of $S_1$:

\begin{align} \tag{5} \int_{S_1} \textbf{F} \cdot \hat{n}_{S_1} \mathop{dS} &\approx \textbf{F}(\rho_0, \theta_0 - \frac{\Delta \theta}{2}, z_0) \cdot \hat{n}_{S_1} \Delta \rho \cdot \Delta z \\ &=  F_{\theta}(\rho_0, \theta_0 - \frac{\Delta \theta}{2}, z_0) \cdot \Delta \rho \cdot \Delta z \end{align}
Similarly, we can compute for $S_2$, the face across it:
\begin{align} \tag{6} \int_{S_2} \textbf{F} \cdot \hat{n}_{S_2} \mathop{dS} \approx  F_{\theta}(\rho_0, \theta_0 + \frac{\Delta \theta}{2}, z_0) \cdot \Delta \rho \cdot \Delta z \end{align}

Summing, we have
\begin{align} \tag{7} \int_{S_1 + S_2} \textbf{F} \cdot \hat{n} \mathop{dS} &\approx \Big( F_{\theta}(\rho_0, \theta_0 + \frac{\Delta \theta}{2}, z_0) - F_{\theta}(\rho_0, \theta_0 - \frac{\Delta \theta}{2}, z_0) \Big) \cdot \Delta \rho \cdot \Delta z \\ 
&= \frac{F_{\theta}(\rho_0, \theta_0 + \frac{\Delta \theta}{2}, z_0) - F_{\theta}(\rho_0, \theta_0 - \frac{\Delta \theta}{2}, z_0)}{\Delta \theta} \cdot \Delta \rho \cdot \Delta \theta \cdot \Delta z \end{align}
and then we get that
\begin{align} \tag{8} \lim_{\Delta V \to 0 }\frac{1}{\Delta V} \int_{S_1 + S_2} \textbf{F} \cdot \hat{n} \mathop{dS} &= \lim_{\Delta V \to 0 } \frac{F_{\theta}(\rho_0, \theta_0 + \frac{\Delta \theta}{2}, z_0) - F_{\theta}(\rho_0, \theta_0 - \frac{\Delta \theta}{2}, z_0)}{\Delta \theta} \\ 
&= \lim_{\Delta \theta \to 0 } \frac{F_{\theta}(\rho_0, \theta_0 + \frac{\Delta \theta}{2}, z_0) - F_{\theta}(\rho_0, \theta_0 - \frac{\Delta \theta}{2}, z_0)}{\Delta \theta} \\ 
&= \frac{\partial F_{\theta}}{\partial \theta} \big|_{(\rho_0, \theta_0, z_0)} \end{align}

Repeating this argument for the rest of the faces, I eventually get

\begin{align} \tag{9} \mathop{div} \textbf{F} = \frac{\partial F_{\rho}}{\partial \rho} + \frac{\partial F_{\theta}}{\partial \theta} + \frac{\partial F_z}{\partial z} \end{align}

which is incorrect.

Comment: [This answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4723549/949989) shows how to do it.

Comment: @KurtG. I've read the answer, and have added an edit to my question.

Comment: Progress! According to formula (3) in that answer you write the components of $\mathbf{F}$ as functions of $\rho,\theta,z$ then dot $\mathbf{F}$ with your lovely $\mathbf{n}$ and integrate over $\rho,z\,.$ If you take a concrete example and perform all steps I can check the result.

Comment: @KurtG. I'm trying to solve for a general vector field, so I could compute the divergence eventually.

Comment: You did not do what  I said. That $\mathbf{F}$ in your (2) is expressed in cylindrical coordinates. We need it in Cartesian coordinates as *function* of the parameters $\rho,z$ that parametrizes the black surface. These parameters were $u,v$ in the linked answer. Don't overthink it. This is pullback and we'll get there.

Comment: I am a bit confused though about the start of OP. What *is* the surface you are integrating over. In which coordinates and how is it given *initially* ?

Comment: I'm given vector field $\textbf{F}=F_{\rho} \hat{\rho} + F_{\theta} \hat{\theta} + F_z \hat{z}$, and my aim is to derive the div formula in cylindrical coordinates, by summing the six surface integrals of $\textbf{F}$ over the faces of the cube in $\mathbb{R}_{\rho \theta z}$ , displayed on the left.

Comment: We have a vector field $\mathbf{F}$ whose components are given in cylindrical coordinates and want to integrate $\mathbf{F}\cdot\mathbf{n}$ over one face of a "cube" that is also given in cylindrical coordinates. The outward pointing unit normal vector at that black surface has only one non zero component which is $n_\theta=-1\,.$ Therefore 
$\mathbf{F}\cdot\mathbf{n}=-F_\theta\,.$ Integrate this over $(\rho,z)\,.$
The problem is actually quite simple and pull back of differential forms is not needed. A better example to learn this was the link in my first comment.

Comment: Note that there seems a sign error in your formula (1) and that this normal vector's components are Cartesian. The answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4704518/converting-a-cross-product-typically-found-in-electrodynamics-between-coordinate/4704593#4704593) shows that the normal vector with cylindrical components is $(0,-1,0)$ as I just mentioned.

Comment: Just saw your last edit. I you absolutely want to do all of this in cylindrical coordinates (to prove the limit formula for div Cartesians are just as good) I do not think that you can repeat all of this naively for all six faces. Esp. the two curved ones might be tricky. In short. See [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4666412/divergence-on-the-hyperbolic-plane-vs-3d-divergence-in-cylindrical-coordinates/4666592#4666592) for divergence formulas w.r.t different bases and in particular the metric $g$ in cylindricals.

Comment: @KurtG. Thanks, I guess that either $\frac{\partial F_{\theta}}{\partial \theta} \neq \lim_{\Delta \theta \to 0} \frac{F_{\theta}({\textbf{p}+\Delta \theta}) - F_{\theta}(\textbf{p})}{\Delta \theta}$ or $\frac{\partial F_{\rho}}{\partial \rho} \neq \lim_{\Delta \rho \to 0} \frac{F_{\rho}({\textbf{p}+\Delta \rho}) - F_{\rho}(\textbf{p})}{\Delta \rho}$. I don't know tensor analysis (or Weyl-Voss). So I'll just wait until I'll learn it.